# how to use gparted to partion 2 drives as 1

Tags: 14.04, software-recommendation, hard-drive, gparted

I have a lenovo t43 and a SATA extra HD drive instead of the CD drive; and I have in it a 250 GB hard drive and in my HD caddy I have a 40 GB hard drive.

I would like to use gparted to partition these 2 drives as 1. I would like to have the 250 GB as an extended part of the 40 GB because I already have Ubuntu Installed on it. They are right now not side by side. I am not sure how to do this, so please list the procedure step by step.

[image]

Comment: post the screenshot of your gparted partition editor tool on your question.

Comment: i posted screen shot links

Comment: no need to upload the screenshots to fb. Just upload it to imgur.com and post back the link here.

Comment: it says i dont have enough reputation to post images

Comment: just post back the uploaded links on your question.

Comment: i did not see that under images under advanced help

Comment: remove the facebook links and replace it with imgur link.

Answer (score 0):

In response to your question, I refer you to another forum post on same topic, already answered by gunbert and Jobin:
[How to merge an unallocated partition with an extended partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/269045/how-to-merge-an-unallocated-partition-with-an-extended-partition)

*Ammended
This link will help you create a logical partition over two physical drives. :
[How can I create one logical volume over two disks using LVM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/219881/how-can-i-create-one-logical-volume-over-two-disks-using-lvm)

One note of caution: it is mentioned in the above answer that creating a logical volume across the two physical disks, as suggested, could expose you to certain risks involving disk failure. Something to consider.

Here is another post, from Ubuntu Help, you may find useful. It outlines the steps involved for setting up LVM without a fresh install. :
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpLVM-WithoutACleanInstall

Comment: no that’s one drive i have 2