# Showing Low space available when installing software - how can I use a partition mounted in /media to alleviate the situation?

Tags: dual-boot, disk-usage, partitioning

I dual boot Ubuntu with Windows 7.

I am installing some software and it is saying low space available, while one disk is completely empty.

[image]

How can I use the `/media/abhi` partition?

[Screenshot from GParted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sk6yr.png)

Comment: Save your files from `/dev/sda6` and merge it with `/dev/sda7` to use its space for your system (e. g. with `gparted`). **Backup everything first!**

Comment: You've created a small / partition on /dev/sda7, only 20GB, and it's almost full. You can use other partitions for storage and backups, but, usually, not for "installing some software". .../dev/sda6 is empty, there is nothing to backup there.

Comment: @mikewhatever Then why does the screenshot say _394.6 MB used_ for that partition? There is data, even if it might be irrelevant.

Comment: @dessert how to merge , I am new to Linux

Comment: @coder See e. g. [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/269072/507051). You might even be able to do that in your running system. Maybe [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/126250/507051) suits your needs better.

Comment: I am unable to understand, what to do. I have attached screenshot of GParted.