# Merge unallocated partition to root partition

Tags: gparted

I am not able to resize my root. I want to merge the unallocated space to my root partition. My gparted screenshot looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwCvL.png)

Comment: Here is another link which might help https://askubuntu.com/questions/269045/how-to-merge-an-unallocated-partition-with-an-extended-partition

Comment: You are unable to resize your root for one big, obvious reason: It's mounted. Boot a LiveUSB instead, and then you will discover your onboard HDD/SSD partiions resize quite easily.

Comment: Ultimately you should read the docs on using gparted and creating partitions.

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Make sure that you have a good backup of your important Ubuntu files, as this procedure can corrupt or lose data.**

Keep these things in mind:

- always start the entire procedure with issuing a **swapoff** on any mounted swap partitions, and end the entire procedure with issuing a **swapon** on that same swap partition
- a **move** is done by pointing the mouse pointer at the center of a partition and dragging it left/right with the hand cursor
- a **resize** is done by dragging the left/right side of a partition to the left/right with the directional arrow cursor
- if any partition can't be **moved/resized** graphically, you may have to manually enter the specific required numeric data (don't do this unless I instruct you to)
- you begin any **move/resize** by right-clicking on the partition in the lower pane of the main window, and selecting the desired action from the popup menu, then finishing that action in the new **move/resize** window

**Do the following...**

**Note**: if the procedure doesn't work exactly as I outline, **STOP** immediately and **DO NOT** continue.

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, in “Try Ubuntu” mode
- start `gparted`
- **move** the p4 partition all the way left
- **resize** the right side of p4 all the way right
- click the Apply icon

Comment: Thank you for your kind help. I did my partition using bootable usb

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @heynnema.  But I being more of a rookie would do it in a simpler way.  Download the gparted live disk. Make a bootable USB of it. Boot to it. Open Gparted if it doesn't open automatically.

Right click on the root partition. Choose Resize/Move.  Drag the left side to fill the unallocated. Hit Apply. Wait.

Try to reboot.  If it fails then you need a bootable USB of Boot repair.  Fire that up and let it do its magic.